# Embedding HTML into SVG - How can I render the HTML markup correctly in HTML namespaced elements, inline with my SVG?

Tags: html, svg, xhtml

I am making an interactive SVG diagram, that will ultimately be embedded in an HTML page but I would like to make the diagram entirely standalone.

I have created the basic SVG in Illustrator and I've added a script section that has the following:

- A variable that's assigned some JSON (the JSON looks like this)

```
    var infodata =
        [{
          "id" : "step1",
          "title" : "Step 1",
          "info" : "&lt;i&gt;This is DevOps step one&lt;/i&gt;"
        },{etc}];
```

- A function that takes a reference from the clicked svg element and returns the row in the JSON that has that reference.

```
    function findInfo(idValue) {
      for (var i=0; i &lt; infodata.length; i++){
        if (infodata[i]['id'] == idValue){
          return (infodata[i]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

- A function that is invoked by a click event on certain SVG elements and uses the function above to get the explanation of the clicked elem  from the JSON and inserts the `infodata.title` and `infodata.info` into `infoTitle` and `infoText`, in the infopop area.

```
    function showInfopop(evt){
       thisInfo=evt.target;
       thisInfoRef = thisInfo.getAttributeNS(null,'inforef');
       info = findInfo(thisInfoRef);
       infoTitle = info.title;
       infoText = info.info;
       document.getElementById('infoTitleContent').textContent = infoTitle;
       document.getElementById('infoTextContent').textContent = infoText;
    }
```

- The SVG opening tag

```
    <svg
        id="Layer_1"
        data-name="Layer 1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        width="1369"
        height="828"
        viewBox="0 0 1369 828">
```

- Then the SVG for the infopop group element

```
    <g id='infopopGroup'>
      <foreignObject
        x="100"
        y="10"
        overflow="scroll"
        width="150px"
        height="100px"
        requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"
        id="foreignObject_test">
        <xhtml:div  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          class="InfopopRect">
          <xhtml:h4
            class="InfoTitle"
            id="infoTitleContent">
              Info
          </xhtml:h4>
          <xhtml:p
            class="InfoText"
            contentEditable="true"
            id="infoTextContent">
              &lt;i&gt;Click on circles for details of the DevOps lifecycle&lt;/i&gt;
          </xhtml:p>
        </xhtml:div>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
```

It all functions perfectly, except that the HTML markup, in the `info` section of the JSON is rendered literally in the infopop, despite the `xhtml` namespace and the html parent types `<h4>` & `<p>`.
(the `<h4>` & `<p>` **do** pick up the css styles just fine BTW)

**How can I render the HTML markup correctly in HTML namespaced elements, inline with my SVG?**

Robert's answer worked for basic text but not for richer markup in the JSON, such as

```
    var infodata = 
    [{ "id" : "step1", 
    "title" : "Requirements capture", 
    "info" : "<ol>
    <li>Research which users</li>
    <li>Plan your research</li>
    <li>Interview your users</li>
    <li>Write up the requirements</li>
    <li>Work with design team and development team to architect your solution and design the user experience</li>
    </ol>" },
    { "id" : "step6", 
    "title" : "Step 6", 
    "info" : "&lt;i&gt;This is DevOps step six&lt;/i&gt;" }];
```

or

```
      "id" : "step1",
      "title" : "Requirements capture",
      "info" : "&lt;ol&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;Research who your users are&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;Plan your research&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;Interview your users&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;Write up the requirements&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;Work with your design team and development team to architect your solution and design the user experience&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ol&gt;"
```

And FINALLY ;-)  This works! All one line, no line breaks:

`"info" : "&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;Research who your users are&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Plan your research&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Interview your users&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Write up the requirements&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Work with your design team and development team to architect your solution and design the user experience&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ol&gt;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use innerHTML rather than textContent to set the infoText e.g.

```
document.getElementById('infoTextContent').innerHTML = infoText;
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. That worked for a JSON string, such as `"info" : "&lt;i&gt;This is DevOps step six&lt;/i&gt;"` but not for the richer examples I've added above.